# Which of these is the correct circuit for JK flip-flop

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, flipflop

[image: Image of possible flip-flop circuits]

Are both of these correct ? I am seeing both of these in different places

Comment: Neither one is an edge-triggered FF. Have you tried looking at a [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls76a.pdf)?

Comment: Yes they are not edge triggered but are they correct for a non edge triggered one ? Also I couldn't understand the one in the datasheet, there are a lot of other things involved.

Comment: Define "correct" -- what should happen when both J and K are high? This is undefined for a non-edge-triggered JKFF. It either oscillates at some arbitrary frequency, or it is forced into a metastable state.

Comment: Have you tried simulating either of these circuits? They're simple enough that you can do it "by hand", or you can use the CircuitLab editor + simulator that's built into this site.

Comment: I didn't know how to simulate. But I will do it again by hand. And come back

Comment: Ok for the 2nd one (the one with Q output given to K) For J = 0 and K = 1 if I start with Q = 1 then Q' = 0 and if I start with Q = 0 then Q' = 1 .So it seems that the operation of the JK flip flop is dependent on the initial value of Q (or Q'). Is it the case ?

Comment: @DaveTweed Does the output of a flip flop actually depend on the initial start condition that you choose ? That is do you actually have to make sure that it starts with a particular value of Q (say 1) for us to use it in further cases ?

Comment: Ok The first one actually works as expected but I still can't wrap my head around the second one, although many websites show it

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. The second one will inhibit the outputs from ever changing.

The cross coupling arrangement of the second one is correct for a JK flipflop built from two and three input nand gates.

Incidentally the inputs are labelled incorrectly. The J & K should be swapped over.
With this circuit when the inputs are at opposite binary states, it is the input which is set to 1 which sets the diagonally opposite output after the rising edge of the clock. So to set the Q output (top output), it is the the bottom input which should be set to 1 (top input reset to 0). Conventionally the J input is the set input (sets the Q output when set to 1) and therefore the lower input should be called J.

**EDIT**: If the clock signal is a square wave (or something close) it should be converted to very narrow clock pulses by one of the circuits below. Top circuit below creates a positive edge triggered JK flipflop, the bottom circuit creates a negative edge triggered JK flipflop when connected to your first circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPJNNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ok so then that must be I too have no problem with the first one. But in this video he uses the second one https://youtu.be/F1OC5e7Tn_o

Comment: If you read through the comments for that video, you can find that someone has pointed out that as a mistake (the one from your second diagram). And apparently that has been corrected in his next video https://youtu.be/st3mUEub99E?t=25

Comment: the mistake was that J and K is was swapped. The circuit is correct

Comment: @Allen The mistake is much greater than simply that the J and K are swapped. Watch the rest of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st3mUEub99E&t=188s beginning at 188s. The circuit has a race condition, and works only intermittently.